# How to override languages files in wp-content/languages/themes with child theme

Tags: hooks, child-theme, translation, textdomain

I want to create a child theme for TwentyFifteen theme, which will customize a lot of things, including translation. When I install WordPress in my language (Farsi), it includes TwentyFifteen language files in `wp-content/languages/themes`

So when I create a `languages` folder in my child theme and add customized language files to it and  add `load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyfifteen', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' )` to my child theme's `functions.php` my customized language files do not load and instead the files in `wp-content/languages/themes` load. What can I do to override those files?

Answer (score 2):

Since WP 4.6 `load_theme_textdomain()` (and consequently `load_child_theme_textdomain()`) will give priority to .mo files downloaded from WP's online translation platform (translate.wordpress.org). Due to some new code ([here, on line 769](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L755)) these functions will completely ignore your local .mo files if the textdomain is found in the general *languages/* directory.

You can, however, use the more basic `load_textdomain()` function to directly load your .mo file and override strings from the original domain, like this:

```
$domain = 'textdomain-to-override';
$path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages/'; // adjust to the location of your .mo file

$locale = apply_filters( 'theme_locale', get_locale(), $domain );
load_textdomain( $domain, $path . $locale . '.mo' );
```

Comment: Edited my original reply to be more brief and objective.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from the [source of `load_textdomain`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L502) (in WP 4.6):

> If the text domain already exists, the translations will be merged. If
>   both sets have the same string, the translation from the original
>   value will be taken.

In other words, in order to make your translation override TwentyFifteen's, you must make sure your mo-files are loaded first, so they will be regarded as 'the original'. To do this, you can use the fact that a child theme's `functions.php` is loaded before the parent's.

In the parent theme find the function that is loading the textdomain. It probably uses the `after_setup_theme` hook. Make sure your child theme uses the same textdomain as the parent. Then load your textdomain with [`load_child_theme_textdomain`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_child_theme_textdomain/) on the same hook, but with a [higher priority](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

Comment: i tried this: `function blognevisi_setup() {
load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyfifteen', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'blognevisi_setup', 8 );` in which "blognevisi" is my child theme and "twentyfifteen" is my parent theme.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: i think you did not understand my problem, it's not like TwentyFifteen has its own language files in /languages folder. the language files for TwentyFifteen are in wp-content/languages/themes. which loads before my files no matter what!

Comment: I have the same problem.... all the standard solutions online for child translations don't work